# Burninate the [historical] and [outdated] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415872/old-esoteric-c-code) with the tags [outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outdated) and [historical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/historical).

Both of these need to be killed with fire, in my opinion.

Comment: Only requires 80 edits. :)

Comment: Sounds like a community challenge to make this post outdated and historical ;)

Comment: @Oded: I'll post my feature request to replace [status-completed] with [status-outdated] later.

Comment: 80 edits *or* deletions.

Comment: If they're historical, it seems like they'd be worth saving. Just because they are outdated doesn't mean they should be burninated. :P

Comment: With mah toolkit, it only took ten minutes.  Of course, that included combing through all the questions to VTC, downvote, and flag for extra crispy burnination.

Comment: You missed a *perfect* chance at a great title: "[historical] and [outdated] are historical and outdated."

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[image: Those tags have been BURNED]